# Any reason to use out parameters with the C# 7 tuple return values?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I have just watched a video presenting the [new features of C# 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ju2MuqKf_8). Among others, it introduces the possibility to return a tuple type (e.g.: `(int, int)`, which, I believe, is just a syntactic sugar for `Tuple<int, int>`). Thus, if we have a method returning multiple values, there are 3 possibilities in C# on how to do it:

```
(int first, int second) ReturnTuple()
{
    return (1, 2);
}

int ReturnOutParam(out int second)
{
    second = 2;
    return 1;
}

CustomObject ReturnObject()
{
    return new CustomObject
    {
        First = 1,
        Second = 2
    };
}
```

I believe, there are no more ways to do it - if yes, please, correct me.

Which of those three methods is the right one? And in which cases can we use the remaining two? With every new C# release, I have the feeling that there are one or two design patterns that just became obsolete in the .NET world. Some features were very useful (like generics, partials, LINQ, lambdas, async/await or null propagator). Others are very situational (dynamic, nameof). And then there are those that just don't make sense to me (property auto-initializers, tuple return values or local functions).

Comment: *"Which of those three methods is the right one?"* well, they all work, so in that sense they are all "right". Which one is actually right for a particular scenario will depend on the scenario. Having said that, the second one seems really awkward.

Comment: You could ask the same question about normal parameters. Why declare a method as `f(int a, int b, int c)` instead of `f(Tuple<int, int, int> abc)` or `f(CustomClass abc)`? If the values are logically grouped (eg, you would consider making a class out of them if they were used more often), then use the tuple. If not, separate them out.

Comment: the 3rd method you show forces you to define a class just your need to  return 2 values (and maybe use it nowhere else in your program). out parameters.... I always disliked them (can't tell you why...) Language support for returning multiple values seems a good thing to me. Of course you can do the same in the old way if you prefer

Comment: There is an additional scenario to consider. If the `out` parameter is optional, then modelling the return as a tuple forces you to change the method name signature, since methods cannot differ by only the return type. Using an `out` parameter lets you support an extra optional return value without creating a new method name.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First and foremost, a tuple like `(int, int)` is syntactic sugar for `ValueTuple<int, int>`. The differences between `Tuple` and `ValueTuple` are:

- `ValueTuple` is a value type, so there's no need to allocate an object on the heap
- `ValueTuple` is mutable
- `ValueTuple` has (obviously) built-in language support, and it lets you name the tuple items through a custom attribute (`TupleElementNamesAttribute`). With `Tuple`, you'll only get `Item1`, `Item2` etc.

With each new language version some features become obsolete. For instance, the `delegate { }` syntax was superseded by lambdas. You could argue that `out` parameters fits in this category, but that's subjective. Yet all the features need to stay there for backwards compatibility.

For instance, `bool int.TryParse(string input, out int value)` should have become `int? int.TryParse(string input)` with the inclusion of nullable value types to the language, but the old function was already there in the framework, so it had to stay.

My rule of thumb would be: use value tuples for private methods or utility functions, but prefer full-fledged structs for any public API, it just feels cleaner this way. I generally avoid `out` params except occasionally for private methods.

I don't get why some of these new features don't make sense to you:

- Property auto-initializers are *finally* there, they should have been implemented along with auto-properties in the first place, but were probably skipped because of time constraints. It's an obvious win for code readability, and it adds a feature that was always there for fields.
- Tuple return values is the topic of your question, it's also an obvious readability win over the old tuples. Being able to name your tuple items speaks for itself.
- Local functions will mostly prove useful for implementing the iterator pattern, but I occasionally wished to have such a feature and worked around it by using a lambda.

Answer (score 9):

For me it still depends on the situation. For example for `TryParse` it's still more readable to do:

```
if (int.TryParse("123", out var i))
{
   // i
}
```

than

```
var (success, i) = int.TryParse("123");
if (success)
{
   // i
}
```

and in most cases returning more than one value from method is a code smell. You should always wrap what you return into class which describes your values better than `First` and `Second`.

Comment: Worth bearing in mind that if `int.TryParse` returned a tuple you could do `if (int.TryParse("123") is var (success, i) && success) { // use i here...`

Comment: It's just lack of normal pattern matching. Take a look on Rust, which is dealing very good with such constructs

Comment: using out var i is kinda nice, i didnt know that would work