# Will ValueTuples make out parameters obsolete?

Tags: c#, tuples, out, c#-7.0

With the introduction of ValueTuples in C# 7.0 we can now have multiple return values:

```
public (int sum, int count) GetTallies() 
{
    return (1, 2);
}
```

I'm under the impression that the sole reason for `out` parameters is to provide a workaround for the restriction of having only one return value. However, `out` parameters are getting improved as well which says to me that the C# designers don't think they will become obsolete.

Am I missing something or is the reason for the introduction of the `out var declaration` just to ease the use of older libraries?

To clarify the question a bit more: Is there anything I can do with `out`, I cannot do with `ValueTuples`?

Comment: `ref` and `out` are still useful for interop.

Comment: There's also a lot of existing code that uses out parameters. `Dictionary.TryGetValue()` isn't going anywhere, for example.

Comment: ref and out are stackpointers!

Comment: This [very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41109843/any-reason-tu-use-out-parameters-with-the-c-sharp-7-tuple-return-values) was closed as opinion based, I think this one probably will be too.

Comment: i think i'd still opt for an `out` parameter for any try-parse type routines, which is about the only place I use them

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The question got two close votes already for that reason, I'm not sure I understand why, though.

Comment: @TimPohlmann How *isn't* it opinion based?  What fact is there in the answer to "do you think feature X is useful?"

Comment: There's no technical reason why tuples would make `out` parameters obsolete, to the point where you _should_ use them instead, so it's more down to whether people _will_ use them, ergo it's opinion.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I clarified the question now.